# StreamProvider returns no data when used with Navigator

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

The issue is that I don't get any values out of my StreamProviders (which are defined on a global level) within my `Authenticated` route:

```
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      Provider.value(value: userService),
      StreamProvider.value(value: authService.userStream, initialData: null),
      StreamProvider.value(value: userService.userDataStream),
      StreamProvider.value(value: userService.characterStream),
    ],
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

I noticed that it's to do with the logic that I have for my Navigator (if I remove it the provider values are passed down the widget tree as expected). The Navigator I'm using is based around the idea that the app has 3 states: `Not Authenticated`,  `Authenticated` and `Authenticated-First-Time`. I get the value whether I'm authenticated from the `loginStream` (so far everything works):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: loginStream,
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Loading();
        LoginState state = snapshot.data;
        if (state == LoginState.LOGGED_OUT) return LoginScreen();
        if (state == LoginState.FIRST_TIME) return CharacterCreationScreen();
        return Navigator(
          key: navigatorKey,
          initialRoute: "/home",
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) => PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (ctx, _, __) => routes(settings)(ctx),
            transitionsBuilder: pageTransition,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

The thing is that if I'm Authenticated and say in the HomeScreen, then both `userDataStream` and `characterStream` return null even if there's actual data available. If I remove the StreamBuilder + LoginLogic itself and just have the `Navigator` widget returned above, then HomeScreen gets the correct values.

UPDATE:
I noticed that it's not even the StreamBuilder. If I remove the 3 if's within the builder, then the stream values are propagated correctly. Not sure why that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not quite sure if this helps since I´m lacking details but here is what I noticed so far:

1. If you create the objects in the multiprovider for the first time you should not use `.value` - check if this applies.
2. Try cleaning up the if statements in the function body of your StreamBuilder (use if, else if and else keywords.

Also, following your description, it sounds like whenever an if statement is true, returns and thus cancels the build´s function body, the stream somehow resets and defaults to null. Maybe look into that & update your question.

Comment: Hey, `.value` should be the correct way of doing it as I'm reusing already init values. I did try with create, but that doesn't work either. Cleaning up the if statements doesn't work :( And yes, if an if statement is true it somehow resets the stream (I don't read the stream from the if branches)

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
  Provider.value(value: userService),
  StreamProvider.value(value: authService.userStream, initialData: null),
```

To this

```
Provider(create: (context) => userService)
StreamProvider(create:(context) => authService.userStream, initialData: null),
```

Do the same for all the providers that u are registering

> To expose a newly created object, use the default constructor of a provider. Do not use the .value constructor if you want to create an object, or you may otherwise have undesired side effects.
> https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: No, that doesn't help, unfortunately. The values that I'm passing are already initialized as well which makes me believe `.value` is the correct way anyway. Though again, I tried it but no luck